# How to hide New Button once click in Devexpress Grid View

Tags: jquery, aspxgridview

I am using Devex Grid View and i want to hide New Button once click.
How can i achieve this:

Can any one help me on this.
May i use jQuery For that ?

Grid View : (ASPX)

```
  <dx:ASPxGridView ID="dgDepots" runat="server"  ClientInstanceName="grid" OnInitNewRow="dgDepots_InitNewRow"
        KeyFieldName="LocationCode" Width="100%" OnDataBinding="dgDepots_DataBinding" cellstyle-horizontalalign="Center"
        OnRowDeleting="dgDepots_RowDeleting" OnRowInserting="dgDepots_RowInserting" OnRowUpdating="dgDepots_RowUpdating">

        <EditFormLayoutProperties ColCount="1"></EditFormLayoutProperties>

        <Columns>
            <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="LocationName" Caption="Location" PropertiesComboBox-ValueField="LocationCode" PropertiesComboBox-TextField="LocationName"
                VisibleIndex="0">
                <PropertiesComboBox TextField="LocationName" ValueField="LocationCode"></PropertiesComboBox>
            </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
       </Columns>
 </dx:ASPxGridView>
```